# Python - Rename files except specific extensions

Tags: python, file, rename

i want to rename some files in the Current directory

so when i try this below code, it also changes my Script.py file extension

now i want to exclude .py extension from getting renamed

**or maybe is there anyway to rename files without affecting on file extensions ?**

the code i try is :

```
import os 

def rename(path, new_name, numbering, extension):
    list = os.listdir(path)
    os.chdir(path)
    count = numbering
    for i in list:
    os.rename(i, new_name + str(count).zfill(2) + '.' + extension)
    count += 1

path = os.path.abspath('./')

rename(path, 'New', 1, 'txt')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Don't forget to accept an answer (tick the check-mark next to an answer) if it answers your question. In this way your question stops to show up as _unanswered_. Also up-vote good answers. – As you're starting out here, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [what's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and have a look at [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os 

def rename(path, new_name, numbering, extension):
    list = os.listdir(path)
    os.chdir(path)
    count = numbering
    for i in list:
       if not i.endswith(".py"):
          os.rename(i, new_name + str(count).zfill(2) + '.' + extension)
          count += 1

path = os.path.abspath('./')

rename(path, 'New', 1, 'txt')
```

Comment: I guess it was helful